# ElasticSearch Path Hierarchy Tokenizer Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm going with the this example here.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer-examples.html#analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer-examples

My mapping code is below: My mapping code is below: My mapping code is below:

```
PUT file-path-test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_path_tree": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy"
        },
        "custom_path_tree_reversed": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy_reversed"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_hierarchy": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/"
        },
        "custom_hierarchy_reversed": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/",
          "reverse": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "file_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "tree": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree"
          },
          "tree_reversed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree_reversed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/1
{
  "file_path": "/User/alice/photos/2017/05/16/my_photo1.jpg"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/2
{
  "file_path": "/User/alice/photos/2017/05/16/my_photo2.jpg"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/3
{
  "file_path": "/User/alice/photos/2017/05/16/my_photo3.jpg"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/4
{
  "file_path": "/User/alice/photos/2017/05/15/my_photo1.jpg"
}

POST file-path-test/_doc/5
{
  "file_path": "/User/bob/photos/2017/05/16/my_photo1.jpg"
}
```

The query below seems empty.

```
GET / file-path-test / _search
{
  
   "aggs": {
     "FILTER": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "file_path."
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations": {
     "FILTER": {
       "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
       "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
       "buckets": []
     }
   }
```

What is the reason?

Comment: when I make "fielddata": true it was working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you mentioned is quite simple and it does not add some things to the tokeniser field mapping... Basically add the following to the field

```
          "search_analyzer": "keyword",
          "fielddata": true
```

also be sure to aggregate on the full field: `file_path.tree` or `file_path.tree_reversed`

Eg.

```
GET /file-path-test/_search
{
   "aggs": {
     "_doc": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "file_path.tree"
       }
     }
   }
}
```